# How to populate a DropDownList with the names of the columns in a table

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, drop-down-menu, entity

Good Morning

I have a table called **AGG_TREE** contains 4 following columns:

**"COL_AGG", "PARENT_CODE", "FACTOR" and "DATE_CREATED"**

What I've done: dispayed a DropDownList with the names of the columns and when I select the name of a column I displays its data in a view

This is what I can do :

```
AGG_TREEEntities db = new AGG_TREEEntities();

        var query = (from discs in db.AGG_TREE

                     select [ the names of the columns ??? ].ToList();

        List<string> nameOfMycolumns = new List<string>();
        foreach (var item in query)
        {
            nameOfMycolumns .Add(item.[the names of the columns ???]);
        }
        ViewBag.NameOfMycolumns  = nameOfMycolumns ;
        return View();
    }
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can use Reflection here:

```
 Type type = typeof(AGG_TREE); //that would be the name of the class
  List<string> nameOfMycolumns = type.GetProperties()
            .Where(
                prop => prop.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(EdmScalarPropertyAttribute), false).Any() &&
                !prop.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(EdmRelationshipNavigationPropertyAttribute), false).Any())
            .Select(prop => prop.Name).ToList();
 ViewBag.NameOfMycolumns = nameOfMycolumns;
 return View();
```

And in the View you use:

```
 @Html.DropDownList("yourProperty", new SelectList(ViewBag.NameOfMycolumns))
```

Comment: @Jeremy if it works, please consider to accept the answer(checksymbol to the left of the answer). no need to say thank you... it gives us both a little reputation and the other users of this forum can see better that the issue is resolved so it benefits us all. but you are welcome =)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to answer me

Question: the name of my class must be exactly as the name of my table ?

My class:

```
public class AGG_Tree
{
    public string COL_AGG{ get; set; }
    public string CODE { get; set; }
    public int FACTOR { get; set; }
    public DateTime DATE_CREATED { get; set; }
}
```

and my Controller :

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Type type = typeof(AGG_Tree); //that would be the name of the class

        List<string> nameOfMycolumns = type.GetProperties()
          .Where(
              prop => prop.CustomAttributes.Any(attr => attr.AttributeType == typeof(EdmScalarPropertyAttribute)) &&
              !prop.CustomAttributes.Any(attr => attr.AttributeType == typeof(EdmRelationshipNavigationPropertyAttribute)))
          .Select(prop => prop.Name).ToList();
        ViewBag.NameOfMycolumns = nameOfMycolumns;

        return View();

    }
```

Error :

**Error 2   'System.Reflection.PropertyInfo' does not contain a definition for 'CustomAttributes' and no extension method 'CustomAttributes' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Reflection.PropertyInfo' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   C:\ADA Projets\DecisionPortal\Web\Controllers\IrhRegroupementController.cs  28  32  WebPortal**

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand your question

Comment: Edited answer... there was no property CustomAttributes in 4.0 and earlier.

Comment: And AGG_Tree should be the name of the Type of your entity model. Just look under the model in your solution explorer and under the modelxxx.designer.cs

Comment: No need to define an extra class for that... sorry if i confused you

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but why take the place of CustomAttributes?

Comment: You iterate over all properties of the class. there are navigation properties on them and some that are inherited from the base class ... we dont want those.

Comment: For my enterprise please

Comment: Open up the Edmx model in your solution explorer. Then double click the type under the designer. You see that the Class derives from EntityObject. This class has properties and on this properties are attributes(custom attributes) you can use these to filter out exaclty what properties you need.

Comment: I edited the original answer. Should work with 4.0 now

Comment: Thank you verry much, and what is the code in my view, please